# Asking to know if a sentence is correct

Tags: questions

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> When would you let me know have I been accepted?

I felt doubt because it seems there is two questions.

Comment: One question would be "When would you let me know if I have been accepted?".

Comment: So are you saying it is wrong @MichaelHarvey

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. You could say 'let me know if I have been accepted' or 'let me know whether I have been accepted'. You can't just write 'let me know' followed by what you want to know, phrased as a question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions, as you surmise.

So you need to change the sentence slightly - to read:

> When would/will you let me know WHETHER/IF I have been accepted.

The usual question will be phrased with WILL rather than WOULD:

> When will you let me know whether I have been accepted.

The use of WOULD is more likely as a follow up, meaning WOULD YOU BE ABLE TO or WOULD YOU BE PREPARED TO:

> A: I'm sorry I don't have time to talk now
>   B: When would you let me know whether I have been accepted

Answer (score 1):

Function of an interrogative sentence is to raise issue; it doesn't provide data. So the question should be credible, not be contradictory, must have contextual consistency and should be so raised as to avoid ambiguity. That is to say there must be one questioning clause ( mind it we don't mean one question) should it be a simple, complex or compound sentence. The inquisitor must be clear what he wants to know from his subjects or audience. Otherwise the question borders on absurdity. So one sentence, one questioning clause.

- Who said that, to whom and when, in reply to the question, "Do you know thyself?"? Or, ( if he knew himself?)

It can be seen that the question is embedded in the first clause only. The remaining portion even though has a question it is for contextual information.

Your sentence has two questions : one close ended ( last one) and one open ended ( first one). It is ambiguous to the subject who is supposed to answer. There should be one question. Your sentence is grammatically incorrect. Get rid of either of the questions or ask twice. Interrogative sentences and implied questions are totally different.